# Как синхронно вызвать функцию определенное кол-во раз?

Tags: javascript, es2016

Есть такой код:

```
for (const item of [1]) {
   print()
}
```

Можно ли в синхронном цикле проитерироваться определенное количество раз - не имея массива в наличии, по которому происходит итерация?
Возможно ли на лету сгенерить как то итератор в результате которого цикл бы пробегался столько раз сколько необходимо?

Если это невозможно - по другому поставлю вопрос тогда:
Как синхронно вызвать функцию определенное кол-во раз?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для повторения операции заданное количество раз можно воспользоваться конструкцией [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) (цикл со счетчиком)

синтаксис:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
  statement
```

Пример:

```
for (let item = 0; item < max; item++) {
   print()
}
```

Comment: Перебор элементов в данной реализации - внутри цикла - будет осуществляться поэтапно(синхронно)?

Comment: @MikeKharkov да
`function tt() { console.log('f') }
console.log('start'); for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { console.log(i); tt(); } console.log('finish')`

Comment: @MikeKharkov, все зависит от функции `print`

Comment: А как тогда объяснить подобное описание в документации?
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
>> Для for...in обход перечисляемых свойств объекта осуществляется в произвольном порядке.
Для for...of обход происходит в соответствии с тем, какой порядок определён в итерируемом объекте. Эти правила распространяются на циклы while, for, forEach и пр. генераторы?

Comment: @MikeKharkov Имеется ввиду, что из массива элементы могут браться не по порядку) но я чтот такого поведения не замечал)

Comment: @MikeKharkov, не понял вопрос. В ответе ни `for..in` ни `for..of` не используются. Ссылка на конкретную конструкцию дана. В ней нет никаких неясностей, как именно будет происходить перебор.

Comment: @Jour, нет, не это имеется ввиду.